# Why do my Flot y axis labels appear over the axis? JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, flot

I've been working on setting up a site that uses JQuery Mobile and Flot. The idea is that it can show graphs which you can swipe between.

So far I've got this: http://lasmit.co.uk/tmm-graphs/graph2.php

The first graph works fine, but if you swipe to the side the labels appear over the axis line and look off.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flot doesn't work too well when you call `$.plot` on something that is currently not visible.  Your best bet is going to be to move your page 2 and 3 graphs into `pageshow` events:

```
$('#device2').bind('pageshow',function(){    
  $.plot($("#total-inches-graph"), 
    [{  color: "rgb(14, 91, 173)", label: 'Total Measurements', data: totalInchesArray }] , 
    { xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%a" ,minTickSize: [1, "day"] } });
});

$('#device3').bind('pageshow',function(){    
  $.plot($("#weight-graph"), 
    [{  color: "rgb(32, 140, 47)", label: 'Weight', data: weightArray }] , 
    { xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%a" ,minTickSize: [1, "day"] } });
});
```

I made a working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/yZuZb/

Comment: this gave me the clue to fix my problem.  I had applied an ng-show to my flot chart directive in angular.  changing it to an ng-if fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong with the sliding, as the plot renders correctly when a page is accessed directly, for example open the following URL:
http://lasmit.co.uk/tmm-graphs/graph2.php#device2, but then the other pages are rendered incorrectly.

You set the size of the DIV elements, can you try to also set the exact size for the plots?